# Memory static function vs member function

Tags: c++

class A (say), having all static member functions only
class B(say) having only member functions

If i create 1000 instances of class A. As the class contains only static member functions, the memory do not increase even if there are 1 instance or 1000 instances.

However, for class B. If i create 1000 instances, will there be an increase of memory (even the slightest, may be a pointer for each object pointing to set of member functions) ?

If no, then how does the compiler keep tracks of member function information for a particular object ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For starters, you might try outputting `sizeof(A)` and `sizeof(B)`.  But
several things to keep in mind:

- Regardless of the number or types of members, C++ forbids a class to
  have a size of 0, so static members or not, each instance of `A` will
  take some memory; and
- The resolution of non-virtual functions is done entirely at compile
  time, so there is no need for the compiler to add anything to the 
  class for it.  (Virtual functions will typically add the size of one
  pointer to the class, regardless of how many virtual functions your
  class has.)

Answer (score 5):

**Will there be an increase of memory (even the slightest, may be a pointer for each object pointing to set of member functions)?**

**NO.**
Non virtual Member functions do not contribute towards size of objects of a class.
However, presence of a virtual member function will typically increase the size of an class object.

Note that the latter is purely implementation specific detail but Since all known compilers implement the virtual mechanism using `v-table` and `v-ptr`, it is reasonable to assume that almost all compilers will show the same behavior of adding a `v-ptr` to every object of that polymorphic class thus increasing size of the class object by size equivalent to that of `v-ptr`.

Comment: maybe only virtual methods ;)

Answer (score 2):

If we're *just* talking about member functions, the imprint will be the same.  A member function does not take up more memory the more times the class it is contained within is instantiated (as the `this` pointer is passed to it).  Only the data members of the class are going to take up more memory with each class instantiation as they are unique to each instance of the class.

So to answer your second question, it keeps "track" by the user of the `this` pointer which is passed when calling a non-static member function of a class.

Things get a bit more complicated with virtual methods, but your question has not covered that particular idiom.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `sizeof` function to test does function occupy class object's memory.

```
class A{};
class B{   
    void foo(){};  
};  
class C{  
    static void foo();  
};  
class D{
    virtual void foo();  
};  
class E{
    virtual void foo1();
    virtual void foo2();
}
```

`sizeof(A)=1`
`sizeof(B)=1`
`sizeof(C)=1`
`sizeof(D)=4`
`sizeof(E)=4`

First class `A` `B` `C` object's memory is zero. But if they memory is zero ,compile will cann't distinguish those class. So compile add `char` to distinguish those class. So :

`sizeof(A)=1`
`sizeof(B)=1`
`sizeof(C)=1`

So you can find that member functions and static member functions don't occupy memory.So they will not increasing memory.

But if class has virtual function, it will add 4 byte.And it only add 4 byte whether is have how many virtual functions.Because it only add a `vptr` point to virtual table, which hold virtual function's point.

Answer (score 0):

At a lower level, there are no objects, just function calls. An implicit `this` parameter is passed to member functions. When we call `void B::f(){ mem1(); }`, compiler sees it as `B::mem1(this)`. So even if you have millions of objects of class B, there will be a single function `mem1` expecting an object of type class B.

Virtual functions are different. They are looked up from a table, however, lookup result depends on [actual] type of `this` (in `mem1(this)`) and not the object pointed by `this`.

Answer (score 0):

The difference between a static member function and a normal member function is simple. When you call a normal member function the ecx register is set to the address of class instance
you can see an additional

**lea ecx, instance_name[ebp]**

if you deassemble

the member function uses this register for accessing the class
so the memory usage will not increase but the computational time will increase